# LINQTOSQL Help needed

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql

I'm trying to add a column to the following LINQ expression. I want the column to contain a string concatenation of a text value in a many table called WasteItems. The join would be on "Waste.WasteId = WasteItem.WasteId". My problem is I need to display in a single dynamic column a string such as "EW (5); EX (3)" if there was 8 records in WasteItem and the column containing the 2 character string was called WasteItem.EWC. Hope that makes sense, there must be an efficient way since I realise LINQ is very powerfull. I'm new to it and not sure how to start or go about this:

```
    return from waste in this._db.Wastes
           where (from u in _db.UsersToSites.Where(p => p.UserId == userId && p.SystemTypeId == SystemType.W) 
                  select u.SiteId)
                  .Contains(waste.SiteId)
           orderby waste.Entered descending select waste;
```

THANKS IN ADVANCE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should do:

```
wastes.GroupJoin(db.WasteItems, w => w.WastId, wi => wi.WasteId, (w,wi) => new { w, wi })
    .AsEnumerable()
.Select(x => new
{ 
    x.w.Name, 
    Items = string.Join(", ", x.wi.GroupBy(wi => wi.EWC).Select(g => string.Format("{0} ({1})", g.Key, g.Count())))
})
```

Where `wastes` is the result from your query. The `AsEnumerable()` is necessary because Entity Framework can not handle `string.Join`, so that part must be dealt with in memory.

I could not check the syntax, obviously, but at least it may show you the way to go.